# Symfony forms EventListener doesnt return proper html structure

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony, symfony-forms

I've builit form witch is dynamicly modified. I've followed the documentation (http://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#form-events-submitted-data) and I've got one issue.

My goal is to make "model" field updated when user will select "brand" field.

Here's how my listener look like:

```
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('name')
        ->add('brand', EntityType::class, [
            'class' => 'DEERCMS\BrandBundle\Entity\Brand',
            'choice_label' => 'name',
            'multiple' => false,
            'expanded' => false,
        ]);

    $formModifier = function (FormInterface $form, Brand $brand = null) {
        $models = null === $brand ? array() : $brand->getModels();

        $form->add('model', EntityType::class, array(
            'class'       => 'DEERCMS\ModelBundle\Entity\Model',
            'choices'     => $models,
            'multiple' => false,
            'expanded' => false,
        ));
    };

    $builder->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            // this would be your entity, i.e. SportMeetup
            $data = $event->getData();
            $formModifier($event->getForm(), $data->getBrand());
        }
    );

    $builder->get('brand')->addEventListener(
        FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT,
        function (FormEvent $event) use ($formModifier) {
            // It's important here to fetch $event->getForm()->getData(), as
            // $event->getData() will get you the client data (that is, the ID)
            $brand = $event->getForm()->getData();

            // since we've added the listener to the child, we'll have to pass on
            // the parent to the callback functions!
            $formModifier($event->getForm()->getParent(), $brand);
        }
    );

}
```

The ajax call is sending, but it returns exactly the same html structure, My goal is to update field called "model". Here's template:

```
{{ form_start(form, {'attr': {'id': 'form', 'class': 'form-horizontal', 'onChange': 'changed()'  } }) }}
   <div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Marka </label>
          <div class="col-md-9">
              {{form_row(form.brand, {'id': 'test', 'attr': { 'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
           </div>
   </div>
   <div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Model </label>
             <div class="col-md-9">
               {{form_widget(form.model, {'id': 'test1', 'attr': { 'class': 'form-control'}}) }}
              </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
       <label class="col-md-3 control-label"></label>
           <div class="col-md-9">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">{% if is_editing %}EDYTUJ {% else %}DODAJ{% endif %}</button>
           </div>
   </div>
{{form_end(form)}}
```

And here's AJAX call

```
  <script>
function changed() {
    var brand = $('#test');
    // ... retrieve the corresponding form.
    var $form = $('#form');

    console.log($form);
    // Simulate form data, but only include the selected sport value.
    var data = {};
    data[brand.attr('name')] = brand.val();
    // Submit data via AJAX to the form's action path.
    jQuery.ajax({
        url : $form.attr('action'),
        type: "POST",
        data: data,
        success: function (html) {
            console.log(html)
            $("#test1").replaceWith(
                // ... with the returned one from the AJAX response.
                $(html).find("#test1")
            );
            // Position field now displays the appropriate positions.
        }
    });
}
 </script>
```

When I do console.log(html) it shows exactly the same html structure, so it doesn't contain "model" data, which should be retrieved from listener.

I've checked all my relations and they works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by myself!

The reason why it didn't worked was that i had onChange() atribute in form_start, which should be inside form_row(form.brand)